# PostgreSQL ORDER BY column_label behavior in PARTITION

Tags: postgresql, window

I have a SQL query that makes use of PostgreSQL window function that look something like this:

```
SELECT 
 tags.id, 
 tags.title, 
 to_timestamp(posts.published_date) at time zone 'utc' at time zone '+08:00'::date,
 COUNT(1),
 SUM(COUNT(1)) OVER (PARTITION BY tags.id ORDER BY to_timestamp(posts.published_date) at time zone 'utc' at time zone '+08:00'::date ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)\
FROM posts
INNER JOIN post_tag ON post_tag.post_id = posts.id
INNER JOIN tags ON post_tag.tag_id = tags.id
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

Basically it'll return for each `Tag`, how many posts are tagged to it grouped by day (day is the 3rd column while 4th column shows the count). Now the tricky thing is the fifth column where it shows the sum of all posts count before the date of the row itself, for instance the row below:

`1 Entertainment 2019-5-30 5 20`

would mean that for the `Tag` with the ID `1` and named `Entertainment` has a total of 5 posts on 30 May and a total of 20 posts all time *except* 30 May.

Now this works well as intended, but ideally I would prefer to cut down the verbosity by replacing the `to_timestamp(posts.published_date) at time zone 'utc' at time zone '+08:00'::date` in the `OVER` clause to use column ordering. Note that I am already using the column literal ordering in my `GROUP BY` but when I do `ORDER BY 3` in the `OVER` clause its giving me totally wrong result.

I guess my question is, how does `ORDER BY *column ordering*` works in an `OVER` clause?

Comment: What is your origin data and what result you want? Can you give us some examples?

Comment: The expected result is that when I use `ORDER BY 3` in the `OVER` clause it should order by the "third" column when doing the `SUM` on the partition but it is apparently returning the wrong results whereas `GROUP BY 1,2,3` works perfectly where it is actually doing `GROUP BY tags.id, tags.title, to_timestamp..` as expected.